# Unspecific Dataflow Import error in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, csv, import, dataflow

I'm trying to import data into Magento through Dataflow. I've tried both xml and csv files but huge error messages starting with the following keep coming up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl"> <head> <title>
```

(most errors are over 50,000 characters long and contain a combination multiple 'random' errors and code)

It consideres a staging area of a webshop and I've already tried both xml and csv imports, cache cleaning, reïndexing, permission changes through shell and more. When I bring the file back to about 10 records, there is no problem. Around 15 records Magento starts spitting up these errors and finally states that no records are imported. Funny thing is, it actually does import some (seemingly random) records. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: You posted the start of an HTML document — without getting to the meat of the error message no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I've copied the error created a .html from it that I opened in my browser. A complete Magento back-end page popped up stating that a license of a Magento module was not valid. I've disabled the module and importing xml's works like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error was written in plain html. After copying it into a .html file and opening it in a browser a complete back-end Magento page popped up, stating that a module license was not valid (due to creating a staging area). After disabling the module, importing XML's worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the module that was enabled?